# Multiple values to a single index

Tags: java, xml, csv, jaxb

I stored the data from a csv in String[] but single index contains many values
For Example:- a[0] hasJohn Smith Jane Doe Jaan Lepp FooBar. So when I am parsing it to XML it creates 4 context for these 4 values. How can I pass all the name in single athletes node?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
  <Athletes>
    <Name>John Smith</Name>
  <Athletes>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
  <Athletes>
    <Name>Jane Doe</Name>
  <Athletes>
```

Comment: But, what is your question?

Comment: @Codeer How can I pass all the name in single athletes node?

Comment: Your bigger problem is how you are creating your XML file. Let's see the code for which you are creating the XML file.

Comment: DocbuildFactory icFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocBuild icBuilder = icFactory.newDocBuillder();
Document doc = icBuilder.newDocument();
Element mainRootElement = doc.createElementNS("", "Athletes");
doc.appendChild(mainRootElement);
mainRootElement.appendChild(getAthlete(doc, 1, ath.getName()));   
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult console = new StreamResult(System.out);
transformer.transform(source, console);

Comment: I have used this code to create the xml and using this mainRootElement.appendChild(getAthlete(doc, 1, ath.getName())) to add the names